# R -- Repeating a substring task across data frame columns

Tags: r, loops, iteration, transformation

Very simple problem in SAS, not so clear to me in R (beginner).

```
ID <- c('001','002','003')
name1 <- c('ZZ: John','YY: Pete','UU: Judy')
name2 <- c('55: Smith','78: Philips','99: Cortes')
name3 <- c('BB: Jr.','CC: Mr.','56: Dr.')
customer.data <- data.frame(ID, name1, name2, name3)
```

- obviously a silly example, but it captures my data structure

I want to delete the first 4 characters (including space) from each variable such the output looks like this:

```
ID  name1 name2 name3
001 John Smith Jr.
002 Pete Philips Mr.
003 Judy Cortes Dr.
```

.... I need to do this over a long list of variables (not just 3, as in my example).
The same substring function over and over again, then rewrite the data frame as shown.

I could accomplish this easily in SAS (my legacy program / trying to get away from)

```
ARRAY FIRSTSTUFF (3) name1 name2 name3;
ARRAY OUTPUTSTUFF (3) name1 name2 name3;
do i=1 to 3;
FORMAT OUTPUTSTUFF(i) $10.;
OUTPUTSTUFF(i)=substring(FIRSTSTUFF(i),5,10);
end;
```

I am baffled by the R approach to this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the columns of 'customer.data' except the first one (`customer.data[,-1]`) using `lapply`, extract the substring from 5th character to the last character of the string using `substr`, and assign the output back to the corresponding columns of the dataset.

```
 customer.data[,-1] <- lapply(customer.data[,-1],
              function(x) substr(x,5,nchar(as.character(x))))

 customer.data
 #  ID name1   name2 name3
 #1 001  John   Smith   Jr.
 #2 002  Pete Philips   Mr.
 #3 003  Judy  Cortes   Dr.
```

Or in the above you don't have to specify the `stop` if you are using `substring` instead of `substr` (as @Richard Scriven showed in the comments)

```
 customer.data[,-1] <- lapply(customer.data[-1], substring, 5)
```

Or you could use `gsub` to match the characters (`.*`- 0 or more characters) from the beginning till the `:` followed by white space `+`, and replace it with `''` as the second argument for each columns looped by `lapply`.

```
 customer.data[,-1] <- lapply(customer.data[,-1], function(x)
                                          gsub(".*: +", "", x))
```

Comment: Or more simply `lapply(customer.data[-1], substring, 5)`

Comment: @Richard Scriven Thanks, that is more compact.  I didn't know that there is difference between `substr` and `substring`.  Thanks for pointing out that.